# Explain "Please wait while Windows configures..."?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have installed a plug-in to a program on Windows 7.

However when I start the program I get a progress window saying "Please wait while Windows configures Plugin".

What is going on here? It seems that Windows Installer is running. However I would think that it would finish the installation when I installed the plugin.

I am trying to understand what is going on behind the scenes here.
Does Windows ask the Windows Installer every time any program is started if the Windows Installer has an unfinished installation relating to the program or is it something in the program that makes this happen?

I stopped the Windows Installer but this did not help. Some process started it again. How can I find which process this was?

Finally, I deactivated Windows Installer and this "worked".

Comment: We will need details... What Application? What Plugin? And no, Windows Installer isn't normally started every time you open an app...